# rank of $(A+A^{T})$ when $A$ is skew symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, transpose, skew-symmetric-matrices

If $A$ is skew-symmetric and rank of $A$ is $2$. Then what can we say about $\operatorname{rank}\left(A+A^{T}\right)$? I don't find any theorem giving me a concise idea about this. (Maybe I am missing something).

Comment: If $A$ is skew-symmetric, then $A+A^T$ is zero.

Comment: @AnginaSeng I asked the question wrong. But can we say in general about A+A' when A is just general matrix

Comment: One interesting fact is that if $A + A^T$ has positive eigenvalues, then the eigenvalues of $A$ have positive real part.

Comment: As far as rank goes, all we can generally say is that 
$$
\operatorname{rank}(A + A^T) \leq 2\operatorname{rank}(A)
$$

Answer (score 2):

Any vector in the image of $A+A^T$ is clearly the sum of a vector in the image of $A$ and a vector in the image of $A^T$ (up to here, this works with any $B$ instead of $A^T$). Consequently,
$$\operatorname{rank}(A+A^T)\le \operatorname{rank}(A)+\operatorname{rank}(A^T) =2\operatorname{rank}(A)$$

Note that for any $k$ with $2k\le n$, we find an example
$$ A=\begin{pmatrix}0_{k\times (n-k)}&I_k\\0_{(n-k)\times(n-k)}&0_{(n-k)\times k}\end{pmatrix}$$where the inequality is sharp.
On the other hand, even for $k=n-1$, we find an example
$$ A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&\cdots\\-1&0&1&0&\cdots\\0&-1&0&1&\\\vdots&0&-1&0&\ddots\\
&\vdots&&\ddots&\ddots\end{pmatrix}$$
where the resulting rank is $0$.

Comment: Actually the original question is much more convoluted. But as far as I understand given rank of A then we cant say anything about $A+A^{T}$ apart from what you said. The original question is regarding the fundamental matrix in computer vision. I have seen a part saying $rank(F+F^{T})=3$ where $rank(F)=2$ but I guess I need to look for something more to get an answer of this